# add a column from a specific line using awk

Tags: bash, awk

EDIT:

I would like to add a column to a file but only from a specific line onwards. The column to be added is stored in another file, which has several columns and I only want to add the 3rd. The first file has two extra-lines (1st and 2nd line) compared to the second file. I would also like to add an extra string in the second line (at the end of this line)

Here is an example that shows what I want:

```
$ cat file1.txt
file1
index place value
1 A 0.1
2 A 0.3
3 B 0.1
4 B 0.6

$ cat file2.txt
A 1 0.3
A 1 0.4
B 1 0.4
B 1 0.6
```

And this it would be the desired output

```
$ cat output.txt
file1
index place value score
1 A 0.1 0.3
2 A 0.3 0.4
3 B 0.1 0.4
4 B 0.6 0.6
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tail` `paste` and `echo`:

```
awk 'NR==1; NR==2{print $0, "score"} NR>2{a[++i]=$0} NR>FNR{print a[FNR], $NF}' file1 file2
file1
index place value score
1 A 0.1 0.3
2 A 0.3 0.4
3 B 0.1 0.4
4 B 0.6 0.6
```

PS: To get formatted tabular output use `column -t`:

```
awk 'NR==1;NR==2{print $0, "score"} NR>2{a[++i]=$0} NR>FNR{print a[FNR], $NF}' file1 file2|
     column -t
file1
index  place  value  score
1      A      0.1    0.3
2      A      0.3    0.4
3      B      0.1    0.4
4      B      0.6    0.6
```

Comment: thanks @anubhava, and if I want to keep the first line ('file1') in the output?

Comment: there seems to be an extra line containing the string "file1". I suppose one could add `head -n1 file1;` in front of the first `echo` command in your answer. However, if the assumption regarding the "file1" line is true, one would need to use `tail -n+3`.

Comment: maybe I didn't explain well, my output would be as the Ed Morton

Comment: Yes realized that and modified to take care of that. I was under impression that `file1` is just for notional purpose.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, it was my bad, when last question, how the command will be if I the file2.txt has three columns and I want to add only the third column? Should I open a new question or edit this one?

Comment: ok check my updated answer. I have changed answer completely as `awk` alone can do all that.

Comment: @anubha where you tell awk which is the 3rd column the one you like to add? here in `NR>2`?

Comment: Actually you're adding 4th column from file2 not 3rd. And that I am getting using `$NF` in `print a[FNR], $NF`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ paste -d' ' file1.txt <(sed '1s/^/\nscore\n/' file2.txt)
file1
index place value score
1 A 0.1 0.3
2 A 0.3 0.4
3 B 0.1 0.4
4 B 0.6 0.6
```

Comment: perhaps the question changed after your answer but how does it not paste first two columns of file2 as well?

Comment: Yes, the question changed, when I answered file2 only had 1 column. I'm leaving it to @anubhava to deal with the vague and churning requirements :-)